# PHP time logging

Tags: php, video

On my site there I'm using a video player (flowplayer), and my clips are in .flv format.
My question is if there is any way I can create php file which will read/stream data from .flv? Like `feed.php?vid=123`

(Yes i know this can be done by opening file locally and outputing it **but here is the catch**)

Every minute the user is streaming, I want to put that information into mysql. How can I do this? Maybe using a loop and reading file in chunks?  ( `while() ... ?` )

Yes, I know I could do this using javascript, but people could steal my .flv directly by using own player and eat my bandwidth.

Comment: Bandwidth can be protected by limiting which domain making the request or creating a session ID. Also, are you looking for minutes of viewing duration or minutes of streaming duration?

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving up bytes, the bytes can be copied and stored. You can NOT prevent theft of data on a website, because a website which does not serve up data is a logical impossibility.

You can record how many chunks have been sent out, but there's no direct correlation between "X bytes = Y seconds", because video compression ratios are content-dependent. You'd need to parse the .flv data somehow and figure out how many frames have been sent, from which you can then figure out how many seconds/minutes have been displayed.

Once you've got that figured out, then recording "play times" will be the least of your problems.

Comment: You _can_ prevent theft of data using apache server settings to prevent hotlinking, or direct access to resources outside of the local host.

Comment: @Nightfire: You can only TRY to prevent theft. The 'apache settings' are all dependent on the user properly (and honestly) setting the HTTP referer. But it's trivial to forge/fake.

Comment: Hey Marc thanks for your answer.

I dont wanna protect my clip from being stolen but I wanna know how many minutes is user watching this clip.

Isn't possible to use fread and time checking?